# Managing turns in java battleships

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to make a Battleships game in java. The final aim is to implement a GUI version (MVC) but at present I am trying to get the model of the game working using the console output. I have also created a simple game engine to manage the game. I have got the majority of the game working in the sense that the game will automatically place ships (random) for both players, and the user can enter co-ordinates to hit for each player (turn by turn).

The problem I have is that when a player specifies a co-ordinate that they have already hit (be it a miss or a hit on a battleship), it specifies the correct message to the console (You have already hit here, TRY AGAIN) but it passes the turn to the other player without allowing the player to specify another set of co-ordinates to hit.

I am not really sure how to get around this. In the GUI version, I would imagine that this is not incredibly important as when a shot has been fired, the JButton on the grid will just disable so it is unclickable???

I have included code snippets for my PlayingBoard class:

```
public int shootAtShip(int x, int y) {
//0 = empty, not hit
//10 = not empty, missed
//11 = hit on a battleship

        //Check if co-ordinates are out of bounds
        if(x >= playingStatus.length || x < 0 || y >= playingStatus[0].length || y < 0) {
            System.out.println("Your specified move was invalid");
        }
        //If grid location was empty, player has missed
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 0) {
            playingStatus[x][y] = 10;
            System.out.println("You missed...");
            return playingStatus[x][y];
        }
        //If grid location has already been hit
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 10 || playingStatus[x][y] == 11) {
            System.out.println("You have already shot here! Try again...");
        }
        //Hit in a field with Aircraft Carrier
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 1){
            playingStatus[x][y] = 11;
            this.carrierHit++;
            System.out.println("You hit an Aircraft Carrier");
            if(this.carrierHit == 5) {
                System.out.println("You destroyed the Aircraft Carrier");
                fleet.remove(carrier);
            }
        }
        //Hit in a field with Battleship
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 2) {
            playingStatus[x][y] = 11;
            this.battleshipHit++;
            System.out.println("You hit a Battleship");
            if(this.battleshipHit == 4) {
                System.out.println("You destroyed the Battleship");
                fleet.remove(battleship);
            }
        }
        //Hit in a field with 1st Destroyer
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 3) {
            playingStatus[x][y] = 11;
            this.destroyerHit++;
            System.out.println("You hit Destroyer #1");
            if(this.destroyerHit == 3) {
                System.out.println("You destroyed the #1 Destroyer");
                fleet.remove(destroyer);
            }
        }
        //Hit in a field with 2nd Destroyer
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 4) {
            playingStatus[x][y] = 11;
            this.destroyer2Hit++;
            System.out.println("You hit Destroyer #2");
            if(this.destroyer2Hit == 3) {
                System.out.println("You destroyed the #2 Destroyer");
                fleet.remove(destroyer2);
            }
        }
        //Hit in a field with Patrol Boat
        if(playingStatus[x][y] == 5) {
            playingStatus[x][y] = 11;
            this.patrolHit++;
            System.out.println("You hit a patrol boat");
            if(this.patrolHit == 2) {
                System.out.println("You destroyed the Patrol Boat");
                fleet.remove(patrol);
            }
        }
        return playingStatus[x][y];
    }
```

Game engine:

```
public void play() {
    while(player1.board.isGameOver() == false || player2.board.isGameOver() == false) {
        System.out.println("Player 1 ----------------------------");
        player1.board.printBoard();
        player1.board.printFleet();
        System.out.println("Player2 -----------------------------");
        player2.board.printBoard();
        player2.board.printFleet();
        System.out.println(currentTurn + " - It is this players turn");
        System.out.println("Please enter target co-ordinates: ");
        String move = userinput.nextLine();
        int movex, movey;
        movex = -2;
        movey = -2;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(move, ",");
        if(tokenizer.countTokens() == 2) {
                movex = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                movey = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }
        if(currentTurn == "player1") {
            player2.board.shootAtShip(movex, movey);
        }
        if(currentTurn == "player2") {
            player1.board.shootAtShip(movex, movey);
        }
        if(player1.board.isGameOver() == true) {
            System.out.println("Player2 has won - Sorry");
            break;
        }
        if(player2.board.isGameOver() == true) {
            System.out.println("Player1 has won - Sorry");
            break;
        }
        nextTurn();
    }
}

public void nextTurn() {
    if(this.currentTurn == "player2") {
        currentTurn = "player1";
    }
    else {
        currentTurn = "player2";
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: You could use a `turn` counter, basically `if (turn % 2 == 0)` then it's player 2's turn, everything else is player 1

Comment: You don't have to edit out your question (in fact, that's a **bad** idea).  If an answer helped you, accept it (and I think you have already); if you solved it, write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would not advance the turn if shootAtShip does not return a success value. So on getting 10 or 11 returned from shootAtShip, set a flag that means to not advance the turn.

Comment: Yes doing something like okToProceed which is default false and only set to true if shootAtShip returns something other than 10 or 11. okToProceed = shootResult != 10 && shootResult != 11; or something like that.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work; seems to loop into a shot twice displaying in the console You missed..., THEN, You have already shot here! Try again...     ; Even though say co-ordinate (0,0) is empty...and stays on this players turn

Comment: Actually, what might be much better is to return a new status flag for missing (like 15) and not saving it on the board.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the previous comment. I haven't fixed the problem where it is displaying 2 error messages...on a genuine missed shot now it will display the 2 messages (You missed..., You already shot here...) and pass on the turn correctly. On a shot that has already been done, it displays the 1 correct message (You already shot here...) and doesn't pass the turn. I think there is a problem with the return statement somewhere that I'm not seeing.      Thanks for the input so far

Comment: I don't think the return statement is exiting the method when a user has missed; not sure why though?

Comment: Update: I have solved this; I changed the type of the shootAtShip method to String and created a state variable. I basically updated this with the relevant info (hit, miss or alreadyshot) in the if statement and return at the end of the method and it appears to work all good now...Thanks for the input, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You shoud make a nested loop from just after the message "is player turn" to just before the call of next turn. This loop should repeat while the player status is 10 or 11